# $0/free transactions in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I have built a voucher/coupon system in Stripe and have the following scenario.

Customer voucher value: $50 
Item price: $25

The voucher system works out that the total amount the customer will have to pay is $0 and they will have $25 remaining on their voucher code.

My issue is that I am unable to put a $0 charge through on Stripe though I would really like to keep this as the way all charges are processed as the customer's fulfilment system uses Stripe for the other info it needs such as shipping address.

Does anyone know if it is possible to process $0 or free charges with Stripe?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The minimum charge you can make within Stripe is $0.50. You can however make subscriptions that are free.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do some account checking to see if they have enough balance/coupon value to complete a purchase before charging the user.

skip stripe and charge them on their balance/coupon. Only issue I see with this is the invoicing aspect as it wouldn't be covered by stripe